# Password protect a SharePoint excel document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

I have a excel spreadsheet which is in SharePoint Web App Documents. I need to protect the sheet with password in SharePoint itself, so that it will not be public anymore. Is there any way to password protect the SharePoint excel Document?

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating an excel document on your desktop + password protect it then upload it to SharePoint ?! On top of that, you can give unique permission to that specific file so that only certain users can read or edit it.

**Require a password to open or modify a workbook**
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Require-a-password-to-open-or-modify-a-workbook-10579f0e-b2d9-4c05-b9f8-4109a6bce643

**Applying unique permission in SharePoint:**
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-or-library-02D770F3-59EB-4910-A608-5F84CC297782

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427BD7C-F20A-4F75-8CF2-5359DD45A1A6

Comment: But According to this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361986/how-to-access-excel-protected-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-web-access-web-part-in-s.. protected spreadsheet cannot be a part of excel Web App..?